# Django does not show images and render CSS

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to set a background image and some CSS style to my page, but every attempt I tried seems to have no effect:

- i have a base.hmtl page where I load `{% load staticfiles %}`
- in `settings.py` I have set up `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and `STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webapp/static')]`
- In `setting.py` `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` is under installed apps
- the `CSS` folder is located in the main directory under `static`, and the image is as well under `static/img`

here is how i am trying to load this page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<h1>Welcome!</h1>

{%load staticfiles%}
<img src="{% static '/img/background.jpg'%}"/>


{% endblock %}
```

While in my `base.html` I load my stylesheet in this way:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'webapp/CSS/style.css'%}">`
and as well in `base.html` I load `statifiles`

I attach here my folder structure, maybe I have missed something there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed Google Chrome was keeping displaying me a cached version of my page, I had to delete Google Chrome cache with settings --> advanced --> clear browsing data.